# Git Hooks inside PyCharm running in incorrect environment

Tags: python, git, pycharm, anaconda

I have recently started a new project in PyCharm, finally utilizing anaconda environments. However, after trying to make my first commit through PyCharm, it appears to be using my native python, not the environment set in PyCharm. I've tried to restart PyCharm several times, restarted my computer, and reinstalled the virtual environment.

Here is a copy of pre-commit hook:

```
set -e

# Run linters and tests
source scripts/lint.sh
```

The linter is the following: (`which python` has been added to highlight the issue)

```
set -e
set -v

which python

flake8 ~project name~
mypy ~project name~
pytest -x
black --check --fast --quiet ~project name~

set +v
```

I am running the commit through PyCharm -> VCS -> Commit. Inside PyCharm, the commit fails

[image]
(below this are a large amount of mypy errors, but note the environment)

However, if I run the commit from the terminal with `$ git commit -m "testing commit"` the commit works. It provides the following response:

[image]

This is the correct virtual environment inside of the project, seen here:
[image]

Am I setting something up incorrectly? I vastly prefer PyCharm's VCS and would prefer not to have to use git from the terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PyCharm doesn't run git hooks under the virtual environment. The relevant ticket in the bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12988

Comment: Thank you for linking this ticket. Looking at it, I guess I can only learn to run git from the command line in the near future. Thank you.

Comment: Issue was fixed in PyCharm 2021.2.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me.

I was getting the following error:

```
18:37   Commit failed with error
            0 file committed, 1 file failed to commit: Update pre-commit hooks
            env: python3.7: No such file or directory
```

When I navigated to `.git/hooks/pre-commit` in my project repo, it turned out that the shebang line is `#!/usr/bin/env python3.7`.

This was an issue, since calling python3.7 on my MacOS would end up with the following:

```
zsh: command not found: python3.7
```

I could have either added a global python3.7 or, alternatively, updated the shebang. I went with the latter one and changed the shebang line to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I know it's a long time since the question was asked, but this should be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the aforementioned PyCharm ticket won't be fixed soon (it's there since 2014).

This hack below works for me; [I added this to the PyCharm ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12988#focus=streamItem-27-3989958.0-0):

> This is a slightly annoying workaround that works for me:
>
> 1. Close PyCharm.
> 2. `cd /your/project/dir`
> 3. Open PyCharm from the command line: `PYENV_VERSION="$(pyenv local | head -1)" open /Applications/PyCharm.app/`.    I'm using macOS, you
>      should adapt the `open` command to your OS.
>
> I have to do it every time I switch projects, otherwise the `pylint`
>   [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) hook doesn't work. If you have a
>   similar config for your projects (Python version and not using
>   PyLint), just run PyCharm from the CLI once.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the auto-generated pre-commit file (located in your project dir at `.git/hooks/pre-commit`) to add the path to your virtual environment, replacing:

```
# start templated
INSTALL_PYTHON = 'PATH/TO/YOUR/ENV/EXECUTABLE'
```

with

```
# start templated
INSTALL_PYTHON = 'PATH/TO/YOUR/ENV/EXECUTABLE'
os.environ['PATH'] = f'{os.path.dirname(INSTALL_PYTHON)}{os.pathsep}{os.environ["PATH"]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me: `PyCharm 2020.3` on `Windows 10`

What I did is to rename the `.git\hooks\pre-commit` -> `.git\hooks\pre-commit.py`

and created a new `.git\hooks\pre-commit` with next content:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
/c/<PATH-to-YOUR-Python>/python.exe $BASEDIR/pre-commit.py $@
```

Worked as a charm!